# In Flask-SQLAlchemy, where do I initialise and store the database object?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a website using Flask and SQLAlchemy in Python, and having great fun so far.

There is something I'm not sure about, however. The following code is used to connect to the database:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'bla'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

How do I reuse this object in different files, though? I have tried storing it in `g`, but this causes problems in the database models, when I try to use the database outside a web request's scope. Is there a standard method to make `db` accessible in multiple files/classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in a `__init__.py` file under your project folder. This way, your application becomes a package and you can re-use the variables. For example, if your project is called myproject, then you could have

```
myproject/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    views.py
```

Now, in modules such as models.py, you can just do:

```
from myproject import db
```

Comment: This results in `ImportError: No module named myproject`. Is "myproject" simply the name of the folder that contains the project? Or is this something I have to configure before I will be able to use it this way?

Comment: 'myproject' is just an example. Use whatever folder name you have in your project. So yes, it is the name of the folder that contains the project. I think you should read a little about packages in python. It will help you understand why and how `__init__.py` is used.